Building a class to apply styling and behavior to targeted tkinter widgets and can't get them to behave together
I wanted a button with a bit more on it's face, a fancy button, and ended up building a FancyButton class that will wrap a "surface" defined by tkinter widgets in a series of frames and apply a cascade of styling behavior options (hover, click) that make the gang of them look and behave like one big button matching one of two built-in style themes (xpnative, winnative), and over two color schemes.
The goal is to be able to drop it in to other tools and make some fancy buttons. I have a test app with an array of fancybuttons with different widgets, and they're all interactive, able to pass on their bits and bobs, with a level of control over interactivity on a per-widget level (would you like interacting with the checkbutton to engage the fancybutton surface click? That is a settable detail). I even have a way to pass font-size information through surface definition using a suffix on the name parameter.
I've had every individual component working at some point or another, but I cannot get them all to behave together. It could be because I am dumb and lazy. It could be that the predictive text generators are dumb and lazy. It could be that there are some weird quirks of tkinter or a poorly designed execution flow. I'd appreciate any help, or insights.
Here's a link to all the scripts I've made so far, and some file explanations.
https://github.com/sb4ssman/PythonTools/tree/main/FancyButtonLab
tmbtestapp.py - simplest example of the basic behavior working in 1 app state, note the correct relief shadow
fbtest20.py - I have dropped this into several scripts and as long as I don't use certain widgets it's servicable. The test scripts in this naming scheme are all a version of the class and an accompanying test-app.
fblibtests + FancyButtonStyleLibraries - these were an attempt at fully enumerating every detail to make it easier to gain control pinpoint a color to change. It did not make it easier.
fblibtest1 + FancyButtonStyleLibrary.py
fblibtest2 + FancyButtonStyleLibrary2.py - this one is close to functional like fbtest20; note the fontsizes successfully pass through to the radio buttons.
fblibtest3 + FancyButtonStyleLibrary3.py or FancyButtonStyleLibraryNEW.py or FBStyleLibShort.py
A note: the host script or app is supposed to have a component that switches it's overall style/color, where most of the components respond to the theme and color changes globally. The FancyButton class is supposed to work within that, and only apply special styling to the widgets on fancybutton surfaces so that they fancybuttons match the vanilla buttons of the applications theme/color state.
I run (one of) the apps, and use the controls to cycle through the app's four states and observe the appearance and behavior of the FancyButtons and their surfaces' child widgets. I'll also confirm the interactive behavior of the buttons and their widgets by clicking and observing the corresponding prints in the console.
I EXPECT my FancyButtons to all look beautiful.
When they do not, I edit the code, and something else breaks in a way that I'm unable to anticipate.
Examples of odd behavior: style "leaks" - styles applied to a fancybutton's widgets are not isolated to the button's surface; widget picking up a background color, or hover or click behavior when not intended; or failure to get assigned a background color, or hover or click behavior.
Examples Specific-state issues:
In the Retro (winnative) theme, light color scheme: the frame relief shadow is darker than it should be - the toggle theme and dark mode checkbox are supposed to be outside the scope of the fancybutton class and the button can be a landmark for appearance. This issue is pretty pervasive and difficult, but from previous testing the border color of a frame needs to be removed in order for it to take the default but sometimes it doesn't like being set to ("") I was doing it wrong, but there is definitely a way to make it look right and making it happen consistently eludes me.
Depending upon the version of the app they all have different components working but none of them in unison.

Please try to create a [mcve] example. Stackoverflow isn't designed to review and improve a whole repository of codee.
